# EditText show data filled before

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm developing an app and i need to put some information about the user. So, I'm using some EditText to write the name and after click on a button to save it on the sqlite database.

My question is... How can the name that the user inserted before be there? When he are opening that activity again.

Cumps

Comment: pull last entry from db, or put it into shared preferences everytime user hits a button. and clear if he saved it to db

Comment: You need to save it forever?

Comment: I can insert it on the db. Probably i need to do some condition to check if the field is empty on the db and if not it should appear and the user could change it. Its something like that? It should be only one row in the db, and only change it not adding more

Comment: @user3128188 : Do you really need to use a database just for a user name? It would be simpler from a coding point of view to just use `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @Squonk : Well, isn't only the name, there are some more fills. Probably I will have to put it on the db because of later relations with tables.

Comment: @user3128188 : OK, in that case you just need to use a db query to get the user name. If the `Cursor` which is returned has no data then you know the user hasn't entered / saved their user name yet. In that case leave the `EditText` blank (perhaps with a 'hint' saying "Enter user name here"). If the db query *does* return a result then simply fill the `EditText`.

Comment: @Squonk : Do you know some URL with example? Thanks!